# Renewal Opportunity Button

Tags: javascript, custom-button

Hoping someone may be able to help me here **NOT A DEVELOPER!**

Inherited Org with a button on a Custom Object called Support Contract. When clicked this button creates a New Opportunity with Product Items and a Support Contract record as well. Configuration Converter won't work on this as it's a js button so i can't get it to work in Lightning.

The js button:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")} 

if (confirm("You are about to create a NEW opportunity to renew this contract. Click OK to confirm.")) { 
var result = sforce.apex.execute('SupportContractRenewal' , 'renewOpportunity', {sContractId:'{!Support_Contracts__c.Id}'}); 
if(result.length==2) { 
alert(result[1]); 
}else{ 
window.open("/"+result[0],"myWindow"); 
} 
}
```

The button calls an Apex Class i believe which is 201 Rows long:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZPwe.jpg)

[image]

I can't get my head round this at all, i've asked in the community but just been given threads / trailhead but it still makes no sense to me.

Anyone out there who could offer some solid advice please?

Comment: You need a developer on this project. It's so small that you may want to work with a local freelancer rather than a consulting firm, but you need a resource who can build you a small Lightning component to your specifications.

Comment: Thanks David, nothing i can do to try and work on this then?

Comment: It's certainly something you could learn if you're so inclined! However, this is a task that needs development in JavaScript and a small amount of Apex. It's *not* a big job, but it is a job for a developer.

Comment: What is the goal? Just to make this functional in Lightning? Or are you looking to understand what the apex class does?

Comment: I would like to make this functional in Lightning and also understand what the Apex Class does. Business needs are that this must be added to the system and for adoption purposes that is obviously very important too.